# Bootstrap Modal wanting to autofocus on OK button

Tags: model-view-controller, less, bootstrap-modal

I have a Modal. There is a OK button. I want the focus on the button. I have tried autofocus, however it focuses for a second and then goes away.

The code within _Layout.cshtml is:

```
<!-- modal that can notify users of errors -->
<div id="error-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="error-modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Notice</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul>
                    <!-- ko foreach: ModalErrors -->
                    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code within the Less file is:

```
#error-modal, #info-modal, #action-modal {
    .modal-dialog {
        z-index: 1100;
    }
    .modal-content {
        border-radius: 0 4px;
        //border-radius: 0;

        ul {
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
    }
    .modal-footer {
        button {
            border-radius: 0;
        }
        .btn-primary {
            background-color: @seal-yellow;
            border-color: @seal-grey;
            color: @seal-black;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If using bootstrap 3 you can focus elements once the modal has been shown on screen by hooking into the modal shown event:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
});
```

See [Boostrap Modal events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this js code to do that:

```
modal = $("#error-modal");
modal.find('.btn-primary').focus();
```

This code will require jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I had to add id="ok-notice-button" to my button type...use javascript and then:

```
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
        </div>


$("#error-modal").on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $("#ok-notice-button").focus();
});
```